# Python NLP/regex: How to split a long text into two parts, but ensure that sentences are not split up?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I have a text with 50000 characters. I am using an APP to process the text but the APP can only process text up to 10000 characters in length. So I have to separate the text into at least 5 parts.

The simple way to separate the text is text[:10000], text[10000:20000], ..., This way may split a sentence into two parts, which is not what I want.

Another way is using tokenize.sent_tokenize(text) to separate sentences, but the output of this way is a list of all separated sentences. It is too ineffective because I do not want to separate all sentences.

Is there any effective ways to separate a long text into several parts?

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression matches the longest string possible that does not exceed 200 characters and is comprised of one or more sentences. The last character of the matched string is therefore a sentence terminator (a period, question mark or exclamation mark).

```
.{1,200}(?<=[.!?])(?=$| )
```

[Regex 1](https://regex101.com/r/GAqALz/8/) | [Regex 2](https://regex101.com/r/GAqALz/9/)

`(?<=[.!?])` is a *positive lookbehind* that requires the last character matched to be a sentence terminator. `(?=$| )` is a *positive lookahead* that requires the last character matched to be followed by a space or the end of a line.

Note that each matched string may begin with one or more spaces that follow a line terminator.

Comment: .{1,200}(?<=[.!?]) works in regex101 but does not work in python code regex.split(r'.{1,200}(?<=[.!?])', message)

Comment: @user13202738, you need to use `findall` rather than `split`. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I also add \s behind the expression for the text cotainning digital number. But still has some problems. It cannot process text containing new line character. Try this text "Dogs are highly variable in height and weight. \r\n\r\nThe smallest known adult dog was a Yorkshire Terrier.\r\nThe largest known dog was a Saint Bernard which weighed 167.6 kg (369 1⁄2 lb) and was 250 cm (8 ft 2 in) from the snout to the tail.\r\nThe tallest dog is a Great Dane."

Comment: Your example points out two problems. The first is that I did not allow for paragraphs. The second is that I forgot that periods (especially), question marks and exclamation marks could appear in strings without being sentence terminators. In my revision I've assumed that any of those characters is a sentence terminator if and only if it is at the end of a line or is followed by a space. That's imperfect, however ("Dr. Watson, I presume."). The adjustments I made work correctly in the regex test but I don't yet have it working in Python code.